# Simpler way in Java generics to infer a return type based off two other types

Tags: java, generics, interface

What I'm attempting to do in Java is essentially to have an interface that is the combination of two other interfaces (so it has the methods from those two interfaces but none of it's own), and then the two sub interfaces can be exchanged out one at a time, so when a change is made all the methods from one of the two interfaces are kept, while all the methods from the other interface are exchanged out for different ones. Since generics is handling the switch, there's no need to cast in order to get the new methods or have the old methods removed.

So for instance we start out with the interface `AA`, which is a combination of the interfaces `LeftA` and `RightA`, giving it the methods `methodLeftA` and `methodRightA`, then we call `selectLeftType(B)` and now we have the interface `BA` which is a combination of the interfaces `LeftB` and `RightA`, giving it the methods `methodLeftB` and `methodRightA`. With the generics this would essentially allow me to do something like the following: `getStartState().methodLeftA().methodRightA().selectLeftType(B).methodLeftB().methodRightA()`

I have worked out an implementation for this that does work, which I will show here a little further down, but the code is extremely verbose. With just doing types A, B, and C. There are already 30 files, and to add D it would require adding 16 new files and editing 17 existing files. To add E after that would require adding 20 new files and editing 26 existing files. So while this could be acceptable for a small number of options, it'll quickly get out of control with anything more than just a few options. So my question is, is there some simpler, cleaner way to go about doing this?

Note: This was built using Java 7, but I'm open to implementations using Java 8 features.

My current implementation follows (like I said earlier, it's long):

BaseImpl.java

```
package test;

class BaseImpl<CURRENT_INTERFACE> implements Combo<CURRENT_INTERFACE> {

  protected <T extends Combo<?>> T 
      selectLeftTypeBase(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector, Class<T> cls) {
    System.out.println("Switch left type.  New class: " + cls.getSimpleName());
    return selectTypeBase(cls);
  }

  protected <T extends Combo<?>> T 
      selectRightTypeBase(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector, Class<T> cls) {
    System.out.println("Switch right type. New class: " + cls.getSimpleName());
    return selectTypeBase(cls);
  }

  private <T extends Combo<?>> T selectTypeBase(Class<T> cls) {
    try {
      return cls.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodLeftA() {
    System.out.println("Left A specific stuff.");
    return (CURRENT_INTERFACE) this;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodLeftB() {
    System.out.println("Left B specific stuff.");
    return (CURRENT_INTERFACE) this;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodLeftC() {
    System.out.println("Left C specific stuff.");
    return (CURRENT_INTERFACE) this;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodRightA() {
    System.out.println("Right A specific stuff.");
    return (CURRENT_INTERFACE) this;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodRightB() {
    System.out.println("Right B specific stuff.");
    return (CURRENT_INTERFACE) this;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodRightC() {
    System.out.println("Right C specific stuff.");
    return (CURRENT_INTERFACE) this;
  }

}
```

Selector.java

```
package test;

public final class Selector<
    LEFT_A_TYPE extends LeftA<LEFT_A_TYPE> & Combo<LEFT_A_TYPE>, 
    RIGHT_A_TYPE extends RightA<RIGHT_A_TYPE> & Combo<RIGHT_A_TYPE>, 
    LEFT_B_TYPE extends LeftB<LEFT_B_TYPE> & Combo<LEFT_B_TYPE>, 
    RIGHT_B_TYPE extends RightB<RIGHT_B_TYPE> & Combo<RIGHT_B_TYPE>, 
    LEFT_C_TYPE extends LeftC<LEFT_C_TYPE> & Combo<LEFT_C_TYPE>, 
    RIGHT_C_TYPE extends RightC<RIGHT_C_TYPE> & Combo<RIGHT_C_TYPE>> {

  public static final Selector<AA, AA, BA, AB, CA, AC> A = 
                  new Selector<AA, AA, BA, AB, CA, AC>(
                      AAImpl.class, AAImpl.class, 
                      BAImpl.class, ABImpl.class, 
                      CAImpl.class, ACImpl.class);

  public static final Selector<AB, BA, BB, BB, CB, BC> B = 
                  new Selector<AB, BA, BB, BB, CB, BC>(
                      ABImpl.class, BAImpl.class, 
                      BBImpl.class, BBImpl.class, 
                      CBImpl.class, BCImpl.class);

  public static final Selector<AC, CA, BC, CB, CC, CC> C = 
                  new Selector<AC, CA, BC, CB, CC, CC>(
                      ACImpl.class, CAImpl.class, 
                      BCImpl.class, CBImpl.class, 
                      CCImpl.class, CCImpl.class);

  private final Class<? extends LEFT_A_TYPE> leftATypeClass;
  private final Class<? extends LEFT_B_TYPE> leftBTypeClass;
  private final Class<? extends LEFT_C_TYPE> leftCTypeClass;

  private final Class<? extends RIGHT_A_TYPE> rightATypeClass;
  private final Class<? extends RIGHT_B_TYPE> rightBTypeClass;
  private final Class<? extends RIGHT_C_TYPE> rightCTypeClass;

  private Selector(
      Class<? extends LEFT_A_TYPE> leftATypeClass, 
      Class<? extends RIGHT_A_TYPE> rightATypeClass, 
      Class<? extends LEFT_B_TYPE> leftBTypeClass, 
      Class<? extends RIGHT_B_TYPE> rightBTypeClass, 
      Class<? extends LEFT_C_TYPE> leftCTypeClass, 
      Class<? extends RIGHT_C_TYPE> rightCTypeClass) {

    this.leftATypeClass = leftATypeClass;
    this.leftBTypeClass = leftBTypeClass;
    this.leftCTypeClass = leftCTypeClass;

    this.rightATypeClass = rightATypeClass;
    this.rightBTypeClass = rightBTypeClass;
    this.rightCTypeClass = rightCTypeClass;
  }

  public Class<? extends LEFT_A_TYPE> getLeftATypeClass() {
    return leftATypeClass;
  }

  public Class<? extends LEFT_B_TYPE> getLeftBTypeClass() {
    return leftBTypeClass;
  }

  public Class<? extends LEFT_C_TYPE> getLeftCTypeClass() {
    return leftCTypeClass;
  }

  public Class<? extends RIGHT_A_TYPE> getRightATypeClass() {
    return rightATypeClass;
  }

  public Class<? extends RIGHT_B_TYPE> getRightBTypeClass() {
    return rightBTypeClass;
  }

  public Class<? extends RIGHT_C_TYPE> getRightCTypeClass() {
    return rightCTypeClass;
  }
}
```

Util.java

```
package test;

public final class Util {

  private Util() {}

  public static AA getStartState() {
    return new AAImpl();
  }
}
```

Left.java

```
package test;

public interface Left<CURRENT_INTERFACE> { }
```

Right.java

```
package test;

public interface Right<CURRENT_INTERFACE> { }
```

Combo.java

```
package test;

public interface Combo<CURRENT_INTERFACE> extends 
    Left<CURRENT_INTERFACE>, 
    Right<CURRENT_INTERFACE> { }
```

LeftA.java

```
package test;

public interface LeftA<CURRENT_INTERFACE> extends Left<CURRENT_INTERFACE> {
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodLeftA();
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftA<T>> T 
    selectRightType(Selector<T, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector);
}
```

LeftB.java

```
package test;

public interface LeftB<CURRENT_INTERFACE> extends Left<CURRENT_INTERFACE> {
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodLeftB();
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftB<T>> T 
    selectRightType(Selector<?, ?, T, ?, ?, ?> selector);
}
```

LeftC.java

```
package test;

public interface LeftC<CURRENT_INTERFACE> extends Left<CURRENT_INTERFACE> {
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodLeftC();
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftC<T>> T 
    selectRightType(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, T, ?> selector);
}
```

RightA.java

```
package test;

public interface RightA<CURRENT_INTERFACE> extends Right<CURRENT_INTERFACE> {
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodRightA();
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightA<T>> T 
    selectLeftType(Selector<?, T, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector);
}
```

RightB.java

```
package test;

public interface RightB<CURRENT_INTERFACE> extends Right<CURRENT_INTERFACE> {
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodRightB();
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightB<T>> T 
    selectLeftType(Selector<?, ?, ?, T, ?, ?> selector);
}
```

RightC.java

```
package test;

public interface RightC<CURRENT_INTERFACE> extends Right<CURRENT_INTERFACE> {
  public CURRENT_INTERFACE methodRightC();
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightC<T>> T 
    selectLeftType(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, T> selector);
}
```

AA.java

```
package test;

public interface AA extends Combo<AA>, LeftA<AA>, RightA<AA> { }
```

AAImpl.java

```
package test;

final class AAImpl extends BaseImpl<AA> implements AA {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftA<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<T, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftATypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightA<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, T, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightATypeClass());
  }

}
```

AB.java

```
package test;

public interface AB extends Combo<AB>, LeftA<AB>, RightB<AB> { }
```

ABImpl.java

```
package test;

final class ABImpl extends BaseImpl<AB> implements AB {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftA<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<T, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftATypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightB<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, ?, ?, T, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightBTypeClass());
  }

}
```

AC.java

```
package test;

public interface AC extends Combo<AC>, LeftA<AC>, RightC<AC> { }
```

ACImpl.java

```
package test;

final class ACImpl extends BaseImpl<AC> implements AC {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftA<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<T, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftATypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightC<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, T> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightCTypeClass());
  }

}
```

BA.java

```
package test;

public interface BA extends Combo<BA>, LeftB<BA>, RightA<BA> { }
```

BAImpl.java

```
package test;

final class BAImpl extends BaseImpl<BA> implements BA {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftB<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<?, ?, T, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftBTypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightA<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, T, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightATypeClass());
  }

}
```

BB.java

```
package test;

public interface BB extends Combo<BB>, LeftB<BB>, RightB<BB> { }
```

BBImpl.java

```
package test;

final class BBImpl extends BaseImpl<BB> implements BB {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftB<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<?, ?, T, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftBTypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightB<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, ?, ?, T, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightBTypeClass());
  }

}
```

BC.java

```
package test;

public interface BC extends Combo<BC>, LeftB<BC>, RightC<BC> { }
```

BCImpl.java

```
package test;

final class BCImpl extends BaseImpl<BC> implements BC {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftB<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<?, ?, T, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftBTypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightC<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, T> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightCTypeClass());
  }

}
```

CA.java

```
package test;

public interface CA extends Combo<CA>, LeftC<CA>, RightA<CA> { }
```

CAImpl.java

```
package test;

final class CAImpl extends BaseImpl<CA> implements CA {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftC<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, T, ?> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftCTypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightA<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, T, ?, ?, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightATypeClass());
  }

}
```

CB.java

```
package test;

public interface CB extends Combo<CB>, LeftC<CB>, RightB<CB> { }
```

CBImpl.java

```
package test;

final class CBImpl extends BaseImpl<CB> implements CB {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftC<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, T, ?> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftCTypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightB<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, ?, ?, T, ?, ?> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightBTypeClass());
  }

}
```

CC.java

```
package test;

public interface CC extends Combo<CC>, LeftC<CC>, RightC<CC> { }
```

CCImpl.java

```
package test;

final class CCImpl extends BaseImpl<CC> implements CC {

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & LeftC<T>> T 
      selectRightType(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, T, ?> selector) {
    return selectRightTypeBase(selector, selector.getLeftCTypeClass());
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Combo<T> & RightC<T>> T 
      selectLeftType(Selector<?, ?, ?, ?, ?, T> selector) {
    return selectLeftTypeBase(selector, selector.getRightCTypeClass());
  }

}
```

And all this code would allow me to the following:

```
import static test.Selector.*;
import static test.Util.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    getStartState()
      .methodLeftA()
      .methodRightA()
      .selectLeftType(B)
      .methodLeftB()
      .methodRightA()
      .selectRightType(B)
      .methodLeftB()
      .methodRightB()
      .selectLeftType(C)
      .methodLeftC()
      .methodRightB()
      .selectRightType(A)
      .methodLeftC()
      .methodRightA()
      .selectLeftType(B)
      .methodLeftB()
      .selectLeftType(A)
      .methodRightA();
  }
}
```

Comment: I gotta be honest, this is too long -- tl;dr to the max. But generally, it sounds like you're trying to be far too clever with this.

Comment: Dear gods man. If this floats your boat, you could look in to annotation processing...it can do code generation and you can do all of this programmatically. https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/ Annotation processing is a little bit limited (can't modify existing code without hackery) but it can do this sort of thing. Well, or just write something that outputs text. Point is if what you're doing works but it's too big to write by hand, code generation is an option. I will say of course that Java generics just aren't good at this sort of thing.

Comment: This scheme will reliably work without errors if and only if every class that implements any of these interfaces implements all of them. In which case, why are they separate interfaces? This seems a very bizarre thing to do, and your anonymized sample gives no clue as to why you want to do it. What is your real use case?

Comment: @yshavit That's the whole point of the question. This is too long, is there some way to make it smaller? If it were smaller then there wouldn't be a question in the first place :P But yeah, this is why I asked the question before giving the implementation details. As it currently stands, the code is too long and complicated to ever consider using in any kind of production code.

Comment: @Radiodef That's an interesting idea. Honestly no one care's about complexity so long as the programmer doesn't have to write or maintain it. If annotations could be used to generate the code behind the scenes... I'll have to look into it a bit and see what's possible.

Comment: @Douglas That's not entirely true that every class would need to implement all of the interfaces. Imagine if we were to add LeftA, LeftB, LeftC, RightA, RightB, and RightC fields to BaseImpl, and then on BaseImpl each of the implementing methods simply calls the method on the specific field. Then any implementation could be passed down into the BaseImpl. A few things would need to be rearranged to make it work, but it wouldn't be that hard. But this is all a moot point if the complexity that I've shown can't be simplified.

Comment: @Douglas As for use cases, it's an api that dynamically modifies what it can do based on it's state without needing to cast. There are a lot of potential use cases. The specific case that got me thinking on this and experimenting with it was automated testing with Selenium using the Page Object Pattern for a page that has two dropdowns that will use ajax to load new things on to the page depending on what was selected from which dropdown. So while technically that page can do everything from the interfaces, it can't do them until the right thing is selected from the corresponding dropdown.

Comment: @Douglas So while I could expose everything that's in BaseImpl all at once, it makes for a nicer interface not to. That being said, exposing everything at once is a far better option than the mess above for maintainability, and is the option I'll stick with unless things can be simplified. (Sorry that's a long response to get you all the info.)